Excessive AMP Parameters in Page indexing Report
I have a bit of a unique situation with my site. I'm in an industry where pricing fluctuates, so, literally every minute, the price of a product updates programmatically.
This poses a problem for Google Shopping, which we use and are very prominent in. So, our solution is to create an identical product page with a different URL and static pricing and canonicalize that URL to the original product.
What I've noticed is that, in the Page indexing report of Google Search Console, I'm getting 100s of thousands of "Not indexed" warnings, most of them with giant parameters that look like this:
?;;;;;amp;;amp;;amp;;;amp;amp;amp;amp;;amp;;;;amp;amp;amp;;amp;amp;;;amp;;amp;amp;amp;;;;amp;

So, my question is, what is the best way to handle this? Should I block those types of parameters in robots.txt and if so, what is the best format to use for that without blocking anything else important.
Thanks!

Your description doesn't explain why you are using amp; in your URLs. If you only use it to ensure the page is new or unique, a better approach would be to have a single parameter that changes based on date, for example, year-month-day-hour-minute.
